# Formula to calculate stock levels

Tags: google-sheets, inventory-management

I have an inventory spreadsheet with a 'total stock' list with the names of all ingredients I use, a raw materials sheet, and a batch sheet. Whenever I receive a new raw material (e.g cocoa butter) I log it into the sheet and the stock list updates, even if the names differ (e.g unrefined cocoa butter). The formula I'm using to do this is:

```
=INDEX(QUERY('Raw Materials'!$B$2:$F$2000,"select sum(F) where B contains '"&$B4&"' label sum(F)'' "),)
```

When I log a new batch in the batch sheet which contains the ingredient name (colA) and amount used (colB), I would like to have the 'total stock' for that ingredient change accordingly. So, total stock = raw material stock - batches

Is there a way add this to the existing formula so the results are in one cell?

Sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aFT_SZ7V6rDMPQPEauCJrWKbAAMRaiZ6RGhhPGdfo8o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aFT_SZ7V6rDMPQPEauCJrWKbAAMRaiZ6RGhhPGdfo8o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({TRIM('Raw Materials'!B2:B), 'Raw Materials'!F2:F, 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM('Raw Materials'!B2:B), Batches!A:B, 2, 0), 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),Col3 where Col2 is not null group by Col1,Col3"), 
 "select Col1,Col2-Col3 label Col2-Col3''"))
```

[image]

Comment: ah my mistake, I didn't show that some ingredients are the same but have different identifiers like 'organic' and 'unrefined', but should be aggregated in the total stock levels. I've amended the sheet